# Row count in dynamically generated table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a table with header and footer and a default row already created. When I add more rows dynamically I don't get the exact row count. It always returns the correct row count if I add them before.

Below is the code I've written -

```
    <table id="empTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>`enter code here`
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name of Employee</td>
                            <td>Father's Name/Husband's Name</td>
                            <td>Basic</td>
                            <td>Total attendance</td>
                            <td>Clear</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="emp_name" name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input id="father_name" name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>              

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="5">
                                <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button></th>
                        </tr>

                    </tfoot>
                </table>

<script>

            //function to add/remove rows
            $(function() {

                $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
                    var div = $("<tr />");
                    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
                    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
                });
                $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {

                    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

                });
            });


            //function to return value of Dynamic content
            function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
                return '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>'
            }

</script>
```

And I'm using this line to return row count but it's not working -

```
 var rowCount = document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").rows.length;
            $('#btnSave').on('click', function() {
                alert(rowCount);

            })
```

I've tried all the solutions from stackoverflow but not getting why it's not working for dynamic rows whereas same code I saw in a fiddle working.

Please help.

Comment: Don't see `id=btnSave` anywhere. Maybe `#btnAdd`?

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to fetch the row count?

var rowCount = $('#TextBoxContainer tr').length;

Comment: @AlonEitan #btnAdd adds the rows. #btnSave is just to test the alert for rowcount.

Comment: @HaukurHaf I've already tried this. It just returns count as 1 even if I add more rows. However if I add rows before (static) same code gives exact count. Not sure what's the problem with dynamic count.

Comment: @Galacticos You're saying that `alert($('#TextBoxContainer tr').length);` right after `$("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);` then it doesn't give you the correct result?

Comment: @AlonEitan got it working now. 

var rowCount = document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").rows.length; should be inside button click.

Thanks to gaetanoM below.

Comment: done. Thanks to you too for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you create new rows on the fly you need to move this line:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").rows.length;
```

inside:

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function() {
```

And as per @charlietf comment I would suggest to change the row count in:

```
var rowCount = $("#TextBoxContainer tr").length;
```

```js
//function to return value of Dynamic content
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>' +
            '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
            '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
            '<td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' +
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>';
}

$(function () {

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function() {
        var rowCount = $("#TextBoxContainer tr").length;
        console.log('Rows: ' + rowCount);

    })
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
        var div = $("<tr />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {

        $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table id="empTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>`enter code here`
    <tr>
        <td>Name of Employee</td>
        <td>Father's Name/Husband's Name</td>
        <td>Basic</td>
        <td>Total attendance</td>
        <td>Clear</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="emp_name" name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input id="father_name" name="DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input name="DynamicTextBox" type="number" value="" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
            <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button>
        <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="ASavee controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Save&nbsp;</button></th>
    </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Huh! So silly from me. Thanks a lot, am very naive to JS, So what I understand here is since the variable has already been declared and assigned a value, it doesn't get the new rows count on button click.

Comment: be simpler to write, and be more consistent with other code using `var rowCount = $("#TextBoxContainer tr").length;`

Comment: @charlietfl You are right. Thanks so much for the hint.